# Filtering a column of mixed types and objects

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame:

```
NPI.         hcps_code 
1003000126     92300
1003000126     G0101
1003000126.    H0002
```

It has 27 other features and approximately 9 million rows, in the column 'hcps_code' there are mixed data types where some are ints and some are strings, or they're combined.

I need to filter the dataframe based on ones that match:

A) fit within the range 92920 to 93799

B) Match the code 'H0002' or 'G0101"

So far I've tried doing:

```
Surg_mammo_DA = super_clean_df.query('hcpcs_code == G0101')
```

but get the error:

```
UndefinedVariableError: name 'G0101' is not defined
```

Next I try:

```
Surg_mammo_DA = super_clean_df.filter(like='H0002', axis=0)
```

This returns an empty dataframe, since the dtype for the column is object it cant recognize it.

Finally I try:

```
Surg_mammo_DA = super_clean_df.loc[(super_clean_df['hcpcs_code'] == 'H0002') &
                                  (super_clean_df['hcpcs_code'] == 'G0101')]
```

This also returns an empty dataframe due to the object conflict.

So I try changing the dtype of the column:

```
super_clean_df.hcpcs_code = super_clean_df.hcpcs_code.astype(str)
```

However it stays the same, most probably due to the fact that there are values in the feature that are int and string/int combined:

```
hcpcs_code                           object
```

Does anyone have any idea how to filter a dataset based on multiple conditions of one column, and addressing different data types within the column?

Comment: Check your columns type it is object , so `Surg_mammo_DA = super_clean_df.query('hcpcs_code == "G0101"')`

Comment: `filters = df.hcps_code.between(92920 , 93799) | df.hcps_code.isin(['H0002', 'G0101']`, and `df[filters]`?

Comment: And filter is for index and columns not for the values

Comment: @QuangHoang "TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'bytes' and 'int'"

Comment: @Wen-Ben "Surg_mammo_DA = super_clean_df.query('hcpcs_code == "G0101"')" returns an empty dataframe, the only reason I know that its in there is because I can manually see it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write two conditions handling the data types and filter

```
cond1 = pd.to_numeric(df['hcps_code'], errors = 'coerce').between(92920, 93799)
cond2 = df['hcps_code'].isin(['H0002', 'G0101'])
df[(cond1) | (cond2)]



NPI.         hcps_code 

1003000126     G0101
1003000126.    H0002
```